# How can I check whether an user imputed string matches a string in a list?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want to check whether a word in a sentence entered by the user matches at least one string in a list. Here is what I have. My predicate test returns false when i enter for example 'banana car' (it should'nt).

In swish prolog i write enterQuery. When prompted i write 'banana car'. I get back [banana, car][banana, apple]false

```
enterQuery:-
read(X),
processQuery(X).

processQuery(X):-
split_string(X," ", " ", L),
write(L),
test(L).

test(L):-
write([banana, apple]),
common_member(L,[banana,apple]),
write('successs').

common_member(Xs,Ys) :-
member(E,Xs),
member(E,Ys).
```

When I query:

```
?- enterQuery.
|: 'banana car'.
[banana,car][banana,apple]
false.
```

Instead, I expect:

```
?- enterQuery.
|: 'banana car'.
[banana,car][banana,apple]successs
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. You need to show your actual interaction, it is not enough to just say "returns false".

Comment: @Boris OK. In the interpreter (swish prolog) I write: enterQuery. When prompted i enter 'banana car'. The output i get is [banana, car][banana, apple]false Thanks!

Comment: No, not good enough, you should really just copy-paste the actual interactive prompt contents to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary stuff in the code that you show.

Here is how I would do this directly from the top level:

```
?- L = [banana, car], member(E, L), member(E, [banana, apple]).
L = [banana, car],
E = banana .
```

The problem as it currently stands is that your code is expecting a `string`, but you are giving it an atom. With your code:

```
?- enterQuery.
|: "banana car".
[banana,car][banana,apple]
false.
```

**note the double quotes!**

There is still a problem: now, `banana` and `car` in the first list are `string`, and the `banana` and `apple` in the second list are atoms.

Or, to demonstrate:

```
?- read(X), string(X).
|: banana.

false.

?- read(X), string(X).
|: "banana".

X = "banana".
```

So you would need to also make the list you are comparing from `[banana, apple]` to `["banana", "apple"]`.

It is still very messy code, not clear why you would want to read with `read/1` instead of just typing it in as in the very first code snippet at the top of this answer.

EDIT:

If you need to enter a sentence from the top level, nothing stops you from wrapping it in single quotes (for an atom), double quotes (for a string), and still entering it as *an argument to a predicate*!

Here is some example code:

```
string_words(S, Ws) :-
        separators_string(Seps),
        split_string(S, Seps, Seps, Ws).

separators_string(Seps) :-
        findall(C,
                ( char_type(C, white)
                ; char_type(C, punct)
                ),
                Cs),
        string_chars(Cs, Seps).
```

With this loaded:

```
?- string_words("banana car", Ws).
Ws = ["banana", "car"].

?- string_words("Hello, how are you doing?", Ws).
Ws = ["Hello", "how", "are", "you", "doing"].
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris. Replacing [banana, apple] with ["banana", "apple"] did it.

Comment: I use write because i want to emulate a situation where the user enters a any sentence, where each word should be matched to a list of criterion words.

Comment: @JCR The point I am trying to make is that the top level gives you term reading and writing for absolutely free: it is almost always unnecessary to add your own half-baked interactive prompt on top of the top level, which is, well, and interactive prompt _and_ a REPL.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with (a lot of) text parsing, in SWI-prolog you can try the builtin [tokenize_atom](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tokenize_atom/2)/2. Despite the name, it actually can work with other text representations:

```
?- tokenize_atom('apple banana', L).
L = [apple, banana].

?- tokenize_atom("apple banana", L).
L = [apple, banana].

?- tokenize_atom(`apple banana`, L).
L = [apple, banana].
```

Boris already addressed others details...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This is a really nice predicate, haven't seen it before so thank you for showing it!

Comment: `?- tokenize_atom('Agent 007 do 0815',L).` answers 
`L = ['Agent', 7, do, 815].`